# Mutex between docker containers

Tags: c#, docker, mutex

please help.
Description of the problem:
I have a microservice which contains caching logic in Redis. On the server, many instances of this service are raised and they use a single cache.
If all instances receive a request to get data from the cache and there is no data there, then ALL instances send a request to get data to the database, thereby loading it.

Solution.
The solution to the problem is to establish a lock between containers via Mutex when requesting the database. So that while one instance receives data from the database and places it in the cache, other instances wait on a locked mutex and then take it from the cache.

All the logic has already been implemented, the only problem is that a single mutex is created for all containers.
Paul Google rummaged - zero information.
Help me please.

So far, I'm testing the creation of a single mutex on a console application.

Below provided the most standard DockerFile.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["MutexDockerTest/MutexDockerTest.csproj", "MutexDockerTest/"]
RUN dotnet restore "MutexDockerTest/MutexDockerTest.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/MutexDockerTest"
RUN dotnet build "MutexDockerTest.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MutexDockerTest.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MutexDockerTest.dll"]
```

Below is the code from Program.cs

```
Console.WriteLine("Start");
using (var mutex = new Mutex (false, "mutextUltra"))
{
    if (!mutex.WaitOne (TimeSpan.FromSeconds (1), false))
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Another app instance is running. Bye!");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        return;
    }
    RunProgram();
}
void RunProgram()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Console.WriteLine("Hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: No, that's not the solution. There's simply no such thing as a cross-container mutex, nor would it solve problems. No service could work that way, using an N-way distributed mutex. Redis doesn't work that way. BTW `microservice` is a marketing or fashion term. You have services talking to a remote distributed cache. This is always a problem with distributed services and there *are* a lot of ways to solve this, depending on the *actual use case*. .NET itself [has built-in distributed caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: For starters, N-way locking between processes on the same machine would be a serious scaleability problem. Between different machines (containers *are* essentially different machines) it would be impossible to have reliable (never mind fast) distributed locking. It's possible to [implement a distributed lock on Redis](https://redis.io/docs/manual/patterns/distributed-locks/) which works because there's a single lock managed by Redis, but that's not as scalable as more specific solutions

Comment: In lookup scenarios it's better to use a *different* process to refresh the cache, eg every N seconds. If an item isn't found, the service tells that single process/container/service to do the job. If all containers are requesting the same data it means they're probably trying to retrieve the same lookup data.

Comment: You may simply store the "state" of the shared cache also inside redis. Then check that state and if the cache is currently updating according to that state wait and retry later.

Comment: Thank you friends for your answers. I will take into account your comments and try to rebuild the architecture in a more optimal way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem. The fact is that each container acts as a separate session and Mutex is created individually for each container separately. To create a single mutex for all containers, you need to create a Global Mutex by adding the Global\ prefix to its name.

Here is the corrected code

```html
Console.WriteLine("Start");


using (var mutex = new Mutex (false, "Global\\mutex")) //Create Global Mutex
{
    if (!mutex.WaitOne (TimeSpan.FromSeconds (3), false))
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Another app instance is running. Bye!");

        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        return;
    }
    RunProgram();
}

void RunProgram()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Console.WriteLine("Hello");
    }
}
```

Here is the command to run docker containers. It is necessary to set the same --pid --ipc and --volume. The volume directory of the containers must be exactly /tmp/.dotnet/shm/. the global mutex is created there

```html
docker run --name mutexContainer1 --pid=host --ipc=host --volume=C:/mutex:/tmp/.dotnet/shm/ mutexImage
```

Answer (score 0):

The scope of a mutex is usally your local machine. Using docker images, I would assume the scope of the mutex would be within that container.

I think you need to look for a solution, that suppports a wider scope. If you host one image in Azure, and another in AWS how would they know its should be the same mutex?

If you are in Azure, some people are using a blob as the mutex, and aquiring and releasing the "mutex" using [BlobLeaseClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.blobleaseclient?source=recommendations&view=azure-dotnet)

Comment: This should be a comment. The question isn't about cloud at all. Nor would using a cloud service remove the problem, quite the opposite actually

Comment: By the way, a really important note in case you have to run services in different clouds. I'll think about it carefully.